# Ubuntu 18.10 Bluetooth not found

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I've been running Windows 8 on the laptop in question and there was no problem with the bluetooth. After installing Ubuntu 18.10 however - if you go to Settings -> Bluetooth - you get "No Bluetooth found"

```
/etc/init.d/bluetooth start  successfull no complains

ps -e|grep blue //shows bluetoothd running

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; hciconfig -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 
Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci


[ 4409.894028] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 4409.894064] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 4409.894070] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 4409.894073] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 4409.894082] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 4717.903128] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 4717.903131] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 4717.903139] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

The above reveals rt2800pci as the module

```
lsmod|grep rt
rt2800pci              16384  0
```

Next:

```
rfkill list all
```

Returns:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

So the bluetooth is integrated with the wireless card which is working fine. 
The bluetooth deamon is running fine. 
The module is listed.

Why do you think Ubuntu is not recognizing that the bluetooth is there and is giving me the "No bluetooth found" info?

Comment: Your question is not about programming. Consider asking it on https://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after I did an update, then after I turned bluetooth off, when I turned it back on it stopped working with exactly that message.

The solution was to restart my computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing "No Bluetooth Found - Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth in Ubuntu 22.10". You should use these following command. It works for me.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt install --reinstall bluez gnome-bluetooth indicator-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```